# Update multiple records on the same table with different data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a page that contains 6 titles and textareas. I'm looking to allow the user to update them all.

This is the blade file

```
@foreach($page->content as $key => $pageContent)
  <div class="input--textarea flex-3-fr">
    <label class="label-std" for="content">Box #{{ $key+1 }}</label>
    <div class="input--text--big flex-3-fr @if($errors->has('title')){{'has-error'}}@endif">
      <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Box title" value="{{ $pageContent->content_title or '[No Title]'}}"/>

    </div>
    <textarea name="content" class="wysiwyg-markdown-editor" form="form-page" rows="7">{{ $pageContent->content or '[No Content]' }}</textarea>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

This is the controller. Currently it just applies the last value to each record. How could I apply the correct value, to the correct record.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $page = Page::findOrFail($id);

    $pageContents = PageContent::where('page_id', $page->id)->get();

    foreach($pageContents as $pageContent)
    {
      $pageContent->content_title   = request('content');
      $pageContent->content         = request('title');
      $pageContent->update();
    }

    dd($request->all());


    return redirect()->route('info-pages.show', ['id' => $page->id]);
}
```

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/mavinoo/laravel-batch

Comment: you need to use second identifier to select correct page content, you may use page content id ?

Comment: Is your blade working properly???

Comment: @rakib Yes. Outputting as desired.

Comment: What is `the last value` you're referring to? Is it the last PageContent or the last item in the request?

Comment: $page->content is a relation with any other model such as Content. Please specify the relation between page and content.

Comment: After you submit your form you will always get only last because of bad name specification. If you need all you should do something like name="title[]" and accept array of tiles and same for content. On controller then you should foreach over as you have it now but you need to change the update because you are still updating same model.